# AutoMapper failing to convert simple DTO

Tags: c#, automapper

Currently working through some legacy code, changing from DTOs built manually to using Automapper. All been going fine until I came to this relatively simple class:

```
public class JobRoleCompanyTypeDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ResourceDescription { get; set; }
}
```

We use localisation and some strings require translation, so I added this to the automapper config, as I've done for other such properties:

```
cfg.CreateMap<JobRoleCompanyType, JobRoleCompanyTypeDto>()
   .ForMember(dto => dto.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(jrc => jrc.Description.Translate()));
```

But when I actually come to test it:

```
JobRoleCompanyType testJrc = _context.JobRoleCompanyTypes.First();
var mappedJrc = Mapper.Map<JobRoleCompanyTypeDto, JobRoleCompanyType>(testJrc);
```

It refuses to compile, giving the error

> cannot convert from 'MyNamespace.Entity.Model.JobRoleCompanyType' to 'MyNamespace.DAL.Model.JobRoleCompanyTypeDto'

I've mapped plenty of other types in this way, so I'm baffled as to why this one doesn't work. No doubt I've missed something stupid and simple, but I can't see what it is?

Comment: The signature is `Map<TSource,TDest>`. You should use `Mapper.Map<JobRoleCompanyType,JobRoleCompanyTypeDto>()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have confused the order between the source type and the destination type, try this:

```
var mappedJrc = Mapper.Map<JobRoleCompanyType,JobRoleCompanyTypeDto>(testJrc);
```

You can also use another overload that accepts `object` parameter as input and ommit the source type at all:

```
var mappedJrc = Mapper.Map<JobRoleCompanyTypeDto>(testJrc);
```

Comment: @MattThrower the [Getting Started](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#how-do-i-use-automapper) tutorial uses `mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);` as an example. I suspect you reversed the order of the Source and Destination type arguments by accident